# Why is cryptoppsigners.o getting built in PowerDNS with --enable-cryptopp=no?

Tags: autotools

I'm trying to build PowerDNS 3.3.1 without requiring crypto++ as a dependency. The configure script has an option `--enable-cryptopp` to disable use of the library. When I give the `--enable-cryptopp=no` argument during configure, the subsequent build fails when it tries to build `cryptoppsigners.o`.

Unfortunately, I'm not at all familiar with autotools from the development side. I tried digging in anyway.

Looking in `configure.ac`, I can see `AM_CONDITIONAL(CRYPTOPP,test x"$enable_cryptopp" = "xyes")`, which defines the conditional, and in `pdns/Makefile.am`, that conditional is used in a couple of places to guard adding `cryptoppsigners.cc` to a list of sources and `-lcryptopp` to a list of arguments. Despite the presence of these conditionals, the pdns/Makefile still includes `cryptoppsigners.cc` in the list of sources and in the list of arguments. I also see in the Makefile `am__objects_3 = cryptoppsigners.$(OBJEXT)`, which eventually gets added to the `pdns_server` target; from here, it seems I need to figure out how/why this is happening.

In the `pdns/Makefile.in` file, I see `@CRYPTOPP_TRUE@am__objects_3 = cryptoppsigners.$(OBJEXT)`. I don't know how to look up that `@..@..` syntax, but I'm guessing from context that it should only assign the variable if `CRYPTOPP_TRUE` is set. This makes me think that it is set, however, looking at `configure.log`, I see this:

```
CRYPTOPP_FALSE='#'
CRYPTOPP_TRUE=''
```

It seems that as should be, `CRYPTOPP_FALSE` is set and `CRYPTOPP_TRUE` is unset. At this point, I'm stuck. If `CRYPTOPP_TRUE` is unset, why does my Makefile end up with that object in the target list?

**Update**: it turns out that if you just leave the argument off, it does not try to compile `cryptoppsigner.cc`. I'd still love to know what's going on here and if I should even expect the behaviour I was expecting from autotools.

Comment: "If CRYPTOPP_TRUE is unset, why does my Makefile end up with that object in the target list?" This is how optional parts of Makefiles work with automake - by UNsetting the variable, the line becomes NOT commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on here is a bug in their M4 macro [`PDNS_WITH_CRYPTOPP`](https://github.com/PowerDNS/pdns/blob/22d63201cb1a81f7e59caab848af5756ec8d4e7c/m4/pdns_with_cryptopp.m4):

Specifically:

```
  AC_ARG_ENABLE([cryptopp],
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-cryptopp],[use Crypto++ @<:@default=no@:>@])],
    [enable_cryptopp=yes],
    [enable_cryptopp=no]
  )
```

Should be:

```
  AC_ARG_ENABLE([cryptopp],
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-cryptopp],[use Crypto++ @<:@default=no@:>@])]
  )
```

`enable_cryptopp` is being set to `yes` no matter if `yes` or `no` is given as an argument (e.g. `--enable-cryptopp=no`) at the `configure` command line.  Also this has the effect of  `--disable-cryptopp` enabling this feature.

This same error appears to be replicated with different variations in all the `pdns_enable_` prefixed macros as well as `boost.m4` in the [m4 directory](https://github.com/PowerDNS/pdns/tree/22d63201cb1a81f7e59caab848af5756ec8d4e7c/m4).

Comment: Thanks! I submitted a bug to them for now, and I hope to be able to go fix it this weekend. https://github.com/PowerDNS/pdns/issues/1457

Comment: Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ldav1s/028ca9ef1611b0ba1bb8) to get you going.  I've not tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Call './configure' without '--enable-cryptopp' at all as we talked in #powerdns.